# grid data to contours

Tags: polygon, dem, vector-grid, polygon-creation

I have a dataset containing a grid of geo-referenced points that have a corresponding value. I'd like to create geographical areas (polygons) at certain levels within the grid, basically combining all points of a given range (i.e. area1 >1 and <=10, area2 > 10 and <=15, etc.) with each area having its own polygons. The polygons may have holes and parts of one polygon may be within another polygon. What is the best way to go about doing this? Is there an algorithm available or perhaps a feature of a GIS tool that can do this? The best analogy would be a DEM an it's corresponding contours, but this is not a DEM.

Comment: I think you should start by rasterizing your points by interpolation then with a reclassify to make your bands integer then convert the integer raster to polygon.. building hypsometric areas (polygons between contours) is **tedious and frustrating**. How you do this depends on what software you have available.. do you have ArcGIS with spatial analyst extension? QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for "interpolation" tools. You can interpolate contours from any dataset of dispersed point values- not just elevation (DEM); maps of temperature are a frequent example.

In QGIS, this tutorial can guide you through interpolating a raster from your data points, then extracting contours from the raster: 
http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html

There are also interpolation tools in ArcMap's Spatial Analyst extension.

Note that there are different methods of interpolating between your points, and they may produce different results. Here is a guide from Esri introducing some of the differences: 
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/comparing-interpolation-methods.htm